# Download managers for downloading over LAN

Tags: networking, software-rec, lan, download-manager

There are some problems with leeching (downloading files at a LAN) such as prioritizing your downloads and the screen real estate that the generic copy-windows take up.

**What download managers can download files over a Local Area Network?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I love [Teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) as a Windows file-transfer replacement.  It works wonderfully for network copies, too.

Answer (score 0):

[Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/)  for Windows:

> What is Free Download Manager? It is a
>   powerful, easy-to-use and absolutely
>   free download accelerator and manager.
>   Moreover, FDM is 100% safe,
>   open-source software distributed under
>   GPL license. Warning: beware of fake
>   versions.

You can download files over LAN by using drag-and-drop on files in Windows Explorer to the drop box provided by FDM.

Comment: I don't think this works with lan shares.

Comment: It does. I have used it.